# how to compare specific string element with all values in list

Tags: python

while this question is similar to a lot of other questions around, i feel that the specific situation i'm trying to solve here is not contemplated in the other questions.(or i'm just not understanding the solutions)

im trying to figure it out how to implement the following code:

```
if str[i] == (any element from list)
       #do stuff
```

in the context of the program, the code needs to check if the specific string element is a number or a letter, but i imagine there is a simpler solution to "compare string element to every letter and number".

Comment: Could you provide some concrete inputs/outputs?

Comment: `if str[i] in list`

Comment: input example: str = "x+1+2"

the output should be: str[0] == True, str[1] == False, str[2] == True and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to check if a string contains only numbers or a letter you can use [`str.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum):

> Return `True` if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise. A character `c` is alphanumeric if one of the following returns `True`:
> `c.isalpha()`, `c.isdecimal()`, `c.isdigit()`, or `c.isnumeric()`.

**Example Usage:**

```
>>> s = 'a@'
>>> s[0].isalnum()
True
>>> s[1].isalnum()
False
>>> '@pple123.isalnum()
False
>>> 'apple123'.isalnum()
True
>>> {c: c.isalnum() for c in 'x+1+2'}
{'x': True, '+': False, '1': True, '2': True}
```